# two objects one bone?

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, objects, bones

I'm working on starting to make minecraft animations.
modelled my character from ingame, it has glasses on the outter layer, added. done all the steps
but when I try and parent the head and the glasses too the "head" bone, the glasses don't move right in pose mode[image]

Comment: you used automatic weight to glasses ?

Comment: Have you tried parenting the glasses to the head and then assigning the head to the head bone?